# Cannot fetch api data in React production (build). Works fine in develop (build)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm struggling to fetch data from my api in when building my react app. It works fine on local, all the routes are working fine. But when I try to build I can't get the data.

The error I get is **net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT** seems like cors, I've tried to change but no success.

In mongo I allowed all IP's do access my DB.

This is my server application `App.ts`

```
const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000' || 'http://192.168.0.212:3000/',
    credentials: true, // access-control-allow-credentials:true
    optionSuccessStatus: 200
};

config();

const uri = `mongodb+srv:...`;

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).single('image'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));

app.use('/users', userRoutes);
app.use('/posts', postRoutes);
app.use('/about', aboutUsRoutes);

try {
    mongoose.connect(uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true
    });

    app.listen(process.env.port || 5000, () => {
        console.log(`Listening on Port 5000 or ${process.env.port}`);
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Couldnt connect to the DB');
}
```

On my front-end (It's a different application) I'm using axios. The code is:
`api.ts`

I've tried to point CORS to my build address and didn't worked. It's funny because on dev build works fine. And all the links of my back-end api works fine too.

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance =  axios.create({
    // baseURL: "http://192.168.0.241:5000/"
    baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/"
    // baseURL: "https://my-api.onrender.com/"
});

export default instance;
```

On my redux action `index.ts` I have:

```
export const fetchPosts = (page: number) => async (dispatch: ({ type, payload }: FETCH_POSTS_TYPE) => void) => {
    try{
        const limit = 5;
        const response = await api.get(`/posts?page=${page}&limit=${limit}`);

        dispatch({ type: FETCH_POSTS, payload: response.data.posts });
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: FAILED_FETCH, payload: true });
        console.log("ERROR: Couldn't establish connection with database" + err);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that this is a CORS error, this also explain why it works locally and why it doesn't work remotely although all the paths are accessible.

I'd first try if it works without CORS (Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *). `app.use(cors())`(without the options) will do that.

Then this line looks very suspect.

`origin: 'http://localhost:3000' || 'http://192.168.0.212:3000/'`

This will only ever resolve to `origin: 'http://localhost:3000'`

Comment: I've discovered and as you mentioned the problem was on CORS. Thank you!